# DefaultTableModel center text

Tags: java, swing

I have this code wherein I am inserting string data dynamically to JTable as Object type data. I want to align the data inserted to table to center. Please need help in this.

Here goes my code:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
dm.addColumn("Product ID");
dm.addColumn("Product Name");

dm.addColumn("Price");
dm.addColumn("Unit");      

DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);                  

for(ProductBean cu:m){

        Object o[] = new Object[4];
        o[0]=cu.getProid();
        o[1]=cu.getPronm();

        o[2]=cu.getPrice();
        o[3]=cu.getUnit();

        dm.addRow(o);       
}
jTable1.setModel(dm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are adding renderer only to a String.class but your data is Object (possibly number etc)

Change

`jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);`

to

`jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRenderer);`

Comment: Thanks for your got it